# Create new collation with slick for sqlite

Tags: scala, sqlite, slick, natural-sort

I would like to receive natural sorted strings by a slick query (sqlite database). I know that I have to create a new collation and use the new collation. Can anyone tell me is there a way to do this with slick?

Maybe there is a way to create the new collation by falling back to jdbc. This would help, too. But if there is such a way, how can I use the new collation with slick?

Thanx for any help.